# Controlling subfigure captions and subfigure placement

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption, subfig

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption, subcaption}
\begin{document}
  This article is about geometrical figures.
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1_example}
      \caption{The rectangle is a complicated geometrical figure that has 4 edges and 4 vertices while a star is an even more complex geometrical figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image2_example}
      \caption{A simple circle and a spiral}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Geometrical figures}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output

[image]

1. The more verbose caption for subfigure a) produces an asymmetric
   placement of the two subfigures.
2. It would be nicer if there would be more horizontal space between the
   two subfigures.

Is it possible to control these features?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The optional argument for the `subfigure` environment provides the placement of the sub-caption *anchor*. This is used to align the sub-captions vertically. Here is a visual:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \texttt{subfigure} with \texttt{[t]}op alignment

  \medskip

  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip\hrulefill\bigskip

  \texttt{subfigure} with \texttt{[c]}entre alignment (default)

  \medskip

  \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip\hrulefill\bigskip

  \texttt{subfigure} with \texttt{[b]}ottom alignment

  \medskip

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

So I'd use a `[t]`op alignment. Additionally, you can spread out the figures using a number of options.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

  Fixed separation using \verb|\quad| (or \verb|\qquad|, or \verb|\hspace|)

  \medskip

  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption}
  \end{subfigure}\quad
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip\hrulefill\bigskip

  Even spread via \verb|\hfill|

  \medskip

  \mbox{}\hfill  
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill\mbox{}

  \bigskip\hrulefill\bigskip

  Full spread via \verb|\hfill|

  \medskip

  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If your images have different vertical heights and you want to align those as well, you can raise content into place; the default alignment of images would be at the baseline:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\newsavebox{\imagebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

  Default

  \medskip

  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,height=75pt]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption}
  \end{subfigure}\qquad
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,height=5pc]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip\hrulefill\bigskip

  \verb|\raisebox| to vertical top

  \medskip

  % Store largest image in a box
  \savebox{\imagebox}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth,height=75pt]{example-image-a}}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\usebox{\imagebox}% Place largest image
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption}
  \end{subfigure}\qquad
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\imagebox-\height}{% Raise smaller image into place
      \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,height=5pc]{example-image-b}}%
    \caption{This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip\hrulefill\bigskip

  \verb|\raisebox| to vertical centre

  \medskip

  % Store largest image in a box
  \savebox{\imagebox}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth,height=75pt]{example-image-a}}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\usebox{\imagebox}% Place largest image
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption}
  \end{subfigure}\qquad
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\imagebox-.5\height}{% Raise smaller image into place
      \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,height=5pc]{example-image-b}}%
    \caption{This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for what `[t]` does? In the documentation of subcaption package it says that is just the `outer-pos` without describing what it means.

Comment: @adosar: Without checking the source code, `outer-pos` is probably the same as `outer-pos` in the use of a `\parbox` or `minipage`, which provides the `pos`ition of the `outer` anchor point (for adjacent vertical alignment).

Answer (score 10):

- Use the `subfigure` option `[t]` instead of `[b]`.
- To add some horizontal space between the figures, put `\quad`, `\qquad`, `\hfill` or some `\hspace` command between the `subfigure` environments.

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption, subcaption}
\begin{document}
  This article is about geometrical figures.
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{The rectangle is a complicated geometrical figure that has 4 edges and 4 vertices while a star is an even more complex geometrical figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{A simple circle and a spiral}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Geometrical figures}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use package

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{float}
```

Then code like:

```
 \begin{figure*}[ht!]
        \centering
            \subfigure[] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab1}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/1.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files
            } 
            %
            \subfigure[] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab2}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/2.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files
            }
            %
            \subfigure[] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab3}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/3.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files
            }\\ % for new row or line of subfigures
            %
            \subfigure[Caption 4] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab4}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/4.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files
            }
            %
            \subfigure[Caption 5] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab6}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/5.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files
            }
            %
            \subfigure[Caption 6] 
            {
                \label{subfig:lab6}
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{figures/6.pdf} % .png .jpg ... according to supported graphics files 
            }
            %
        \caption{Figure Caption}
        \label{fig:Figure ref}
        \end{figure*}
```

It will give you:
[image]