# Centering pictures in subfloat and overpic

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, subfloats, overpic

I am currently writing my master thesis. To embed two images side by side I use subfloat and for the caption in the images I use overpic. However, I have a problem with the alignment of the second image. It is always aligned at the bottom of the first image. I have tried to center the second image vertically, but I have not figured out how to do that.

[image: Picture positioning]

My code:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
  \subfloat{%
    \begin{overpic}[width=.5\linewidth]{A.pdf}
      \put(0,70){\textbf{a)}}
    \end{overpic}
  }
  \subfloat{%
    \begin{overpic}[width=.5\linewidth]{B.pdf}
      \put(0,70){\textbf{b)}}
    \end{overpic}
  }
\caption[xx]{Picture A and B.}
\label{pic:A_and_B}
\end{figure}
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem. I use this code for all my work and it works very well for all other images as they have similar formats.

Thanks for your help,

Woifi

Comment: I also tried: `valign=c` from `\usepackage{adjustbox}`
But did not work at all

Comment: i was writing an answer then I realised that a much more detailed on already exists https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333249/controlling-subfigure-captions-and-subfigure-placement

Comment: Overpic just seems to break `valign`... if you can avoid using overpic (by using `\caption` in a figure, for exampel), it should be easier

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the best way to do it but I found an solution. Maybe someone has a smiliar problem in the future. I solved it with `\raisebox`:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
  \subfloat{%
    \begin{overpic}[width=.5\linewidth]{A.pdf}
      \put(0,88){\textbf{a)}}
    \end{overpic}
  }
  \subfloat{%
  \raisebox{.3\height}{
    \begin{overpic}[width=.5\linewidth]{B.pdf}
      \put(0,70){\textbf{b)}}
    \end{overpic}}
  }
\caption[xx]{xx.}
\label{pic:xx}
\end{figure}
```

If someone has a better solution I would be glad to hear it.
Thanks,

Woifi